# Non existence of classical $C^1$ solutions for an initial value problem associated to $u_t + |u_x|^2 = 0 \quad \mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider $$u_t + |u_x|^2 = 0 \quad \mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$$
with initial condition $u(x,0)=g(x)$.

How do we prove that it has, in general, no $C^1$ solutions even for smooth initial datum $g$? Can you give an example?

Comment: Use characteristics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this (assuming $u$ is real valued): let $v = u_x$, then taking the $x$-derivative of the equation you get 
$$ v_t + v v_x = 0 $$
being the equation satisfied by $v$. This equation happens to be Burgers' equation and is the standard example for formation of shock waves. You can prove that $v$ in general cannot have $C^0$ solutions by using the method of characteristics (along the characteristic curves $v$ is constant, but two characteristic curves may intersect).

Comment: Are you saying that the Burgers' equation cannot have continuous solutions?

Comment: No, that's not what I said. Clearly the function $v \equiv 0$ is a solution to Burger's equation. But for generic _compactly supported_ initial data, the solution to Burger's equation cannot be continuous for all time.